# WPF, covariance, contravariance, and binding in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, generics, covariance

i need to make a settings manager but i can't use appSettings or applicationSettings because i need specific behaviour (adding/removing settings at runtime, loading from/saving in multiple files...).

The problem i'm encountering is finding a solution to the end result i want. Here is an exemple of what it should look like in a use case :

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    private SettingsManager _settingsManager;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _settingsManager.Add(new Option(){Name = "Option1", DisplayName = "Option 1", DefaultValue = "SomeText", Value = "SomeText"});
        _settingsManager.Add(new Option(){Name = "Option2", DisplayName = "Option 2", DefaultValue = 5});
        _settingsManager.Add(new Option(){Name = "Option3", DisplayName = "Option 3"});
        _settingsManager["Option2"] = 10;
        _settingsManager["Option3"].DefaultValue = Brushes.Black;
        _settingsManager["Option3"] = Brushes.White;

        DataContext = _settingsManager;
    }
}
```

with it's corresponding XAML file :

```
<Window x:Class="AnotherProject.MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type String}">
                <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type int}">
                <Label Content="{Binding}" Foreground="Red"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Brush}">
                <Label Content="{Binding ToString}" Foreground="{Binding}"/> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

I am aware that WPF does not support int and string types and it produces errors, however this is only used as a demonstrative example, the real types would not produce those errors.

I tried inheriting from SettingsProperty, used by appSettings, but it seemed too complex for what i'm trying to get and i couldn't assign values without casting.

I tried using generics but there was a problem in type recognition. The following line did not work unless the object was cast into an appropriate type :

```
_settingsManager["Option2"] = 10;
```

I know ways to achieve some of the use case parts separately, but not one that does all of the above mentioned.

Is it even possible to achieve that?

Update : 
here is what the SettingManager looks like

```
    public class SettingsManager : ObservableCollection<Option>
{
    public SettingsManager()
    {
    }

    public SettingsManager(IEnumerable<Option> options)
    {
        if (options != null)
        {
            foreach(var option in options)
            {
                this.Add(option);
            }
        }
    }

    public Option this[String key]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Where(x => x.Name == key).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        set
        {
            var res = this.First(x => x.Name == key);
            if (res != null)
            {
                this.SetItem(this.IndexOf(res), value);
            }
            else
                this.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public SettingsManager AddRange(IEnumerable<Option> options)
    {
        if (options != null)
        {
            foreach(var option in options)
            {
                this.Add(option);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void ResetAll()
    {
        this.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Reset());
    }
}
```

Comment: You set the `String` and `int` types wrong, you need to declare the `System` namespace in XAML before being able to access those types. Also even you do that I don't think your `DataTemplates` work. It would be helpful if you show the `SettingsManager` class, does that class implement an interface such as `ICollection<Option>`? Or it's just a wrapper class exposing `Add` method and some indexers?

Comment: I've updated the question with the SettingsManager class. Also, i do know it won't work as it is. It's a very simplified code for the sake of demonstrating how i want to be able to use the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ItemsControl` has its `ItemsSource` set to a collection of `Option`, meaning each data item is of type `Option`. So `DataTemplate` with DataType cannot filter on different types of `Value` (a property of `Option`) to apply different templates. In this case you should use `DataTemplateSelector`, define your DataTemplates as resources in XAML for convenience (we can then find them in code behind inside the `SelectTemplate` method):

```
public class OptionTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector {
   public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container){
      var option = item as Option;
      if(option != null){
          var itemContainer = container as FrameworkElement;
          if(option.Value is int){
             return itemContainer.FindResource("intOption") as DataTemplate;
          }
          else if(option.Value is string){
             return itemContainer.FindResource("stringOption") as DataTemplate;
          }
          else if(option.Value is Brush){
             return itemContainer.FindResource("brushOption") as DataTemplate;
          }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

Define the template selector as some resource in XAML:

```
<local:OptionTemplateSelector x:Key="ot">
```

The remaining XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ot}">         
    <ItemsControl.Resources>  
        <DataTemplate x:Key="stringOption">
            <Label Content="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="intOption">
            <Label Content="{Binding Value}" Foreground="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="brushOption">
            <Label Content="{Binding Value}" Foreground="{Binding}"/> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Hmm, last time i tried to use DataTemplateSelectors it didn't go well. But this seems the most obvious and simplest solution.